# ShapePath auto closing

Tags: three.js

I'm having an issue with ShapePath where the shape is automatically being closed when converting to geometry?

```
    var path = new THREE.ShapePath();
    path.moveTo(0, 0);
    path.lineTo(0,50);
    path.lineTo(50,50);


    var shapes = path.toShapes(true);

    for ( var j = 0; j < shapes.length; j ++ ) {
      var shape = shapes[ j ];
      console.log(shape);

      var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {
        color: Math.random() * 0xffffff 
      });

      var geometry = new THREE.ShapeBufferGeometry( shape );
      var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
      scene.add(mesh);
    }
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zbeLk6jw/)

What I'm expecting to have is a L style shape, instead i'm getting a triangle being rendered.

I really just want to extrude the path to a solid L shape.

Any ideas on the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw your intended result if you create an enclosing contour of the L shape like shown in the following example: https://jsfiddle.net/zbeLk6jw/1/

```
var path = new THREE.ShapePath();
path.moveTo(0, 0);
path.lineTo(0,50);
path.lineTo(10,50);
path.lineTo(10,10);
path.lineTo(25,10);
path.lineTo(25,0);
```

Comment: Thank you - is there a way to set have the library do this automatically if a stroke width is specified?

Comment: No. `ShapePath` assumes you draw a 2D shape, not lines.

Comment: No worries. Thanks again!